# Duda al usar printf() y system() en C

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

A traves de un programa en C quiero saber el modelo de mi Raspberry usando el comando system()
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
  printf("Modelo: ");
  system("cat /proc/device-tree/model"); //Comando para saber el modelo de Raspberry en Raspbian
  return 0;
}
```

El programa se compila bien, pero **no secuencialmente**. Al usar gcc lo que me figura es lo siguiente:

**Raspberry Pi Zero W RevModelo:**

Porque no se ejecuta de forma secuencial y como lo puedo corregir para que me aparezca la información en una linea ??

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. En este enlace te dan una explicación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301280/in-c-system-executes-before-printf-even-when-printf-come-first. La solución es ponerle un `\n` al printf para que se vacíe el buffer, o forzar el vacíado con `fflush()`.

Comment: Perfecto ese link, te lleva a donde esta la solución.